# Root Motion error while joining other animations with character

Tags: python, animation, error

I'm getting this error when joining the animations to character from *Godot Game Tools* after clicking on *Add Root Motion*.

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\srija\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\src\operators\rootmotion_controller.py", line 337, in execute
    scene.frame_set(index)
TypeError: Scene.frame_set(): error with argument 1, "frame" -  Function.frame expected an int type, not float
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: That addon is not part of Blender so any errors it produces should be reported to the addon author(s).

Comment: @JohnEason Okay didn't knew that would be the case though. Anyway I found the solution for that ,it was already there on their page. 
Should have checked it there first but still thanks.

Comment: Glad you found the answer. Always worth checking the author's page first for external addons as you've now found! :^)